# Can not call a server side method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, server-side

I have a problem with an aspx page.Interesting thing about it , it worked before but now it didn't.
I want to call a server side method from an aspx page : Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lblo" runat="server" Text='<%#GetPanelImageURL()%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

And my server side code :

```
public string GetPanelImageURL()
{
    return "asdasd";
}
```

This is not working.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%# .. %>` are used for data-binding expressions. Data-binding expressions are resolved when the `DataBind` method of a control or of the `Page` class is called. For controls such as the `GridView`, `DetailsView`, and `FormView` controls, data-binding expressions are resolved automatically during the control's `PreRender` event and you are not required to call the `DataBind` method explicitly (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)).

So you don't call a `DataBind` method for this control, and this expression is not evaluated.

Comment: ok.so do you advice something that appropiate for this situation?

Comment: i just found.I call the bind method of page and it worked.Page.DataBind();

Comment: @Aykut, it depends on your logic. You could either call `DataBind()` for page/control which contain your textbox, or set the value from the code-behund like `lblo.Text = GetPanelImageURL()`

Answer (score 0):

you need `<%= GetPanelImageURL() %>`

Comment: server tags doesn't allow `<%= ... %>` constructs